# Started the process of programming my 2005 Malibu key, then battery died. Now process not working

Tags: chevrolet, key, malibu, program

So I started the process of programming my new 2005 Malibu key as described on this page. I went through 2 10 minutes cycles and everything was working correctly. The security light was turning off after 10 minutes and I thought I would soon have a working key, but then the battery died. So I had to charge my battery and now when I try to go through the process the security light is not turning off after 10 minutes. I thought that maybe the key was programmed now, but it still does not start the car. Well it will start it but only for a second and then it turns off. Do i need to reset the key somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Try disconnecting the battery for a few minutes, reconnect, and try programming again.  You might also have [a faulty passlock sensor](https://repairpal.com/no-start-due-to-failed-passlock-sensor-300#) in your key's ignition lock cylinder that may need replacing.